# Using curl to execute an HTML page on the file system

Tags: curl

I have an HTML file acting as a test runner. When rendered in Chrome or other browser the page loads and executes the needed JavaScript.

How do get the same behavior using curl?

Currently I have this command,
`curl "file:///C:/bb/shenanigan-api-html5/shenanigan.html" --compressed` but this simply returns the html source and doesn't actually execute the page.

Comment: you're bringing the file in for reading, not executing it. have you tried just using execute()?

Comment: No, I just copied the cUrl command from the Chrome developer tools. I'll look into using execute().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curl transfers data it does not have the ability to run JavaScript.  Use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) it has command line options, can read local html files and interacts with JavaScript.

Comment: I see the error of my ways...short of running selenium or reworking for phantomjs, for now I will run the following via the command line `start chrome "../shenanigan-api-html5/shenanigan.html`